# How can I login to any pod within any namespace in kubernetes and run any command?

Tags: kubernetes, awk, kubectl

My requirement is to login into pod without selecting the namespace and the pod name, then providing a command to be run inside it. There was no thread or question that answered the query. Below is a solution that I came up with. If there can be improvements in the same, please provide those.

What I was looking for to build automation or a krew plugin for logging into any pod in any namespace and run any command inside it. It is purely automation based, there are plenty of plugins that do the same work like k9s and other krew plugins but my requirement was more of a generic based and lightweight which could be implemented in a Pipeline without any third-party tools.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question, it's a blog post disguised as a question

Comment: @mdaniel Completely agreed, but I couldn't find any leads on here to follow up for the answer to the above question, so I ended up creating a question. The answer is too detailed, but I was looking for how to improve it with any further inputs. Thanks for checking out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Create a Shell Script

**login.sh**

```
#$1 is namespace $2 is the row number where the pod is located $3 is the command to run inside the pod
#$3 is command can be bash,sh or some command like echo "test"
#Example ./login.sh test-ns 1 bash or ./login.sh test-ns 1 'echo "test"'

pod=$(kubectl get pods -n $1 | grep -v NAME | awk -v i=1 -v j=$2 'FNR == j {print $i}')
kubectl exec -it $pod -n $1 -- $3
```

## How to use it?

*login.sh $namespace $pod_number $command*

**1.** Create the above script, make it executable and copy it in **/usr/local/bin** directory or in the **$PATH** variable

```
chmod +x login.sh
#Check if /usr/local/bin exists in PATH variable, if not then run the export command
echo $PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
cp -p login.sh /usr/local/bin/login.sh
```

**2.** Run **kubectl get pods** to get the pod number in which you want to the command to run

```
helloworld-v1-5dfcf5d5cd-v7xtw   1/1     Running   0          8d
httpbin-56db79f4f5-j2cxz         1/1     Running   1          8d
test-cc5b6bfd-2hhmr              1/1     Running   0          39h
```

And I want to exec into the **second** pod with the shell being **bash**

**3.** Run the command to use the script

```
login.sh default 2 bash
```

## Demo Output

The output would look something like:

```
shubham.yadav@my-MAC:~/k8s $ ./login.sh default 2 bash
root@httpbin-56db79f4f5-j2cxz:/#
```

Another example just to make implementation more clear

```
shubham.yadav@my-MAC:~/k8s $ login.sh qa-test 2 'echo "From the pod Login Succeeded"'
"From the pod Login Succeeded"
```

> **Note:** In case you have a large number of pods in the namespace you can use **NR** utility of awk to get the *column numbers* of the pods.

*kp* is an *alias* for *kubectl get pods*

> **kp | grep -v NAME | awk '{print NR, $1}'**

```
1 details-v1-78d78fbddf-zksf7
2 helloworld-v1-5dfcf5d5cd-wl2nx
3 httpbin-56db79f4f5-wj4ql
4 load-generator-5cdbd66865-fxpbm
5 productpage-v1-85b9bf9cd7-qp79l
6 ratings-v1-6c9dbf6b45-xm6ww
7 reviews-v1-564b97f875-cx86c
8 reviews-v2-568c7c9d8f-xxc86
9 reviews-v3-67b4988599-p98ft
10 test-cc5b6bfd-68tqg
11 test-cc5b6bfd-8q694
12 unset-deployment-7896c75bf6-5w27b
13 web-v1-fc4d58bdc-pcv9p
14 web-v2-7bf5dd654d-684t9
15 web-v3-7567d5d6b9-sqrpg
```

## Creating a Binary for Shell Script

In case if you are interested in creating the binary for the above script, you can follow the following [link](https://tecadmin.net/create-binary-file-from-shell-script/) which lets you create a binary for your above shell script.

You can also change the binary name to a more friendly name from **login.sh** to just **execute**

```
shubham.yadav@my-MAC:/usr/local/bin $ mv login.sh execute
shubham.yadav@my-MAC:/usr/local/bin $ execute qa-test 2 'echo "Binary Name Changed"'
"Binary Name Changed"
```